# Symfony 3.4: Correctly configured service is not found

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have an service class with the class name `NewsService`.

The service is configured as follows:

```
services:
    portal.news:
        class: xxx\NewsBundle\Service\NewsService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

I use Phpstorm with symfony plugin - The plugin finds the service, but Symfony itself does not.

I get the following error message:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You have requested a non-existent service "portal.news".").
```

How I use the service:

1. `{{ render(controller('xxBundle:Widget:renderNews', {'slice_length': 250})) }}`
2. in the Controller `xxBundle:Widget:renderNews`: `$articles = $this->get('portal.news')->getNewestArticles($count);`

   - cache is cleared
   - I checked everything (wrong service configuration, bundle is loaded, syntax is ok, ...)

Comment: In what `yml` you defined it? Are you sure it's injected into the container?

Comment: Try using cli to debug the container to see all services registered `php bin\console debug:container`, also I find it a lot easier just having Symfony 3.3+ autowire services instead of configuring them myself.

Comment: Your problem is probably in `public: true` in your config, as the answer below states. Consider moving to Symfony 4, they rely on Dependency Injection and you don't have to care about such stuff.

Comment: it's defined in the `service.yml` of the bundle. `public: true` doesn't solve it. The debugger doesn't know anything of the service...

Comment: any updates about your problem ? (see last comment on my answer)

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to set `public: true` to your service, because since 3.4 all Symfony services are private by Default.

Also, you should avoid `$this->get()` functions and prefer fetching directly your service from your controller arguments

```
<?php 
use xxx\NewsBundle\Service\NewsService
class MyController {
    public function myAction(NewsService $service)  {}
}
```

Comment: Each other service of the whole project (around 20 service classes) are defined without `public: true` and they works. Why I should avoid calls like `this->get()`? Please explain.

Comment: This documentation says it https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#public-versus-private-services

Comment: Perhaps you can provide your full service .yml configuration so I can better understand what your problem is

Answer (score 1):

Using  Service that needs an argument, you need to declare your service as an alias https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#explicitly-configuring-services-and-arguments

Comment: the argument is defined (the "arguments" in the config excerpt in my question).

Comment: Did you take a look at doc ? I saw that you declare an arguments. I just propose to add an alias ? Please read doc and after ask question !